# bash script to create a HTML nav menu

Tags: bash

A while ago I wrote a javascript program to loop through a directory tree and build a html nav menu file from the first 3 levels of the tree. I now am trying to replicate this using bash, as the JS program requires the IE browser and activeX to run. I am reasonably new to bash, so this is a great learning experience for me.

So, what I have is a structure as follows:

```
-Folder A
    --Folder B
    --Folder C
         --Folder C1
         --Folder C2
               --Folder CC1
    --Folder D
         --Folder D1
    --Folder E
```

etc. You get the point. Anyway, the folder names vary, but each folder has a single text file in it called "foldername.txt". In this file is a single line of text that has the actual folder name to be used on the menu (this is due to the length of some of the names).

I am therefore trying to loop through each folder/subfolder down to level 3 only, read each foldername.txt file in the folder and return the name, whilst maintaining the folder heirarchy. I hope that makes sense. The output is appended with html tags and echoed to a .htm file.

So far I have tried different things. The code below almost does what I want, it will scan directories and return the names as per the text file, but does not maintain heirarchy. I do not have a version of find that includes -maxdepth unfortunately. As you can see, I've tried nested loops as it's only 3 deep, but the recursion continues for each level so that I get duplicate and odd results.

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT=/data/
OUTPUTFILE=${ROOT}/Menu-test.html

# Create first level items - these are static
HEADING="<UL class=navlist1>
<LI><SPAN class=plus><p>-</p></SPAN><A class=''>Level 1 products</A></LI>"

END="</UL>"
L2="<UL class=navlist2>"
L3="<UL class=navlist3>"
LI="<LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN>"
LIEND="</LI>"

echo $HEADING > $OUTPUTFILE;

# set shell options
shopt -s nullglob

# loop through top level dir
for d in $DIR/*/
do
    for file in $(find $d -name "foldername.txt");
    do
        OUT=$(awk '{ print $0 }' $file)
        echo $LI$OUT$LIEND >> $OUTPUTFILE; 
    done

    # loop through second level dir
    for e in $d/*/
        do
            echo $L2 >> $OUTPUTFILE;
            for file2 in $(find $e -type f -name "foldername.txt");
                do
                    OUT2=$(awk '{ print $0 }' $file2)
                    echo $LI$OUT2$LIEND >> $OUTPUTFILE; 
                done
            echo $END >> $OUTPUTFILE;

                # loop through third level dir
                for f in $e/*/
                    do
                        echo $L3 >> $OUTPUTFILE;
                        for file3 in $(find $f -type f -name "foldername.txt");
                            do
                                OUT3=$(awk '{ print $0 }' $file3)
                                echo $LI$OUT3$LIEND >> $OUTPUTFILE; 
                            done
                        echo $END >> $OUTPUTFILE;
                    done
        done
done
echo $END >> $OUTPUTFILE;
```

Sorry for the long post and messy code, but I really wanted to try doing this myself first as this is how I learn best.  So any ideas on how I could get this to work. Please note that I do not have access to Python or any other language, so bash it is.

The output I'm looking for would something like as follows (hyphens are only to maintain formatting and are not in the output):

```
**<LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>**
<UL class='navlist1'> 
    <LI><SPAN class='plus'><p>-</p></SPAN><A class=''>Folder A</A> 
        <UL class='navlist2' style='display:block'> 
            <LI><SPAN class='bull'><p class='bull'>&bull;</p></SPAN><A href='http://www.somewhere.com/index.htm'>Folder A1</A></LI> 
            <LI><SPAN class='bull'><p class='bull'>&bull;</p></SPAN><A href='http://www.somewhere.com/index.htm'>Folder A2</A></LI> 
            <LI><SPAN class='bull'><p class='bull'>&bull;</p></SPAN><A href='http://www.somewhere.com/index.htm'>Folder A3</A></LI> 
        </UL**></A>
    <UL class=navlist1>**
        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder B</A></LI>
        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder C</A></LI>
        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D</A></LI>
           <UL class=navlist2>
                <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D1</A>
                    <UL class=navlist3>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D1A</A></LI>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D1B</A></LI>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D1C</A></LI>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D1D</A></LI>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D1E</A></LI>
                    </UL>
                </LI>
                <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D2</A>
                    <UL class=navlist3>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D2A</A></LI>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D2B</A></LI>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder D2C</A></LI>
                    </UL>
                </LI>
            </UL>
        </LI>
        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder E</A></LI>
        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder F</A></LI>
        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder G</A></LI>
            <UL class=navlist2>
                <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder G1</A>
                    <UL class=navlist3>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder G1A</A></LI>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder G1B</A></LI>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder G1C</A></LI>
                        <LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>Folder G1D</A></LI>
                    </UL>
                </LI>
            </UL>
        </LI>
    </UL>
**</LI>**
```

So, this is the current working output. What I also need to do is include the href link in each of the , however, each level of subfolder will have a different path, in the following structure:

navlist1 = http://www.somewhere.com/here//landing.htm

navlist2 & 3 = http://www.somewhere.com/here/there//index.htm

folder is the actual folder name of the directory, not the name in the text file, obviously the link won't work otherwise.

The lines in bold above should not be in the output.

Thank you.

Comment: `I do not have a version of find that includes -maxdepth unfortunately.`  In that case you also can use the construct `for VAR in $DIR/*/*/*`   which returns all the files+paths up to 3 levels deep. This will shrink your amount of code tremendously.

Comment: Thanks. I originally started out with "for d in $DIR/*/*/*/ thanks to a member on this forum, but I could not get the results I was looking for, so thought nesting would be a better way. Obviously not.

Comment: Bash is very powerful with conditionals and string replacement. The chance is that your original idea with $DIR/*/*/* almost got you where you wanted to be and only needed a few tweaks and a little bash magic. If you try it again I will try to help you to finish it if you like.

Comment: It might be easier to tweak your javascript program for a different interpreter, like rhino or node.js

Comment: Another approach is to try to make your for-loops uniform enough to transfrom them into a function.

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately, due to the way the system is setup, JS is not an option (unfortunately), hence why I'm trying it in bash. Thom - thanks, I can get all the foldernames etc using that method, but what I can't do is figure out how to separate everything whilst maintaining the logical folder structure. I would want the output to look like a standard HTML <UL> list.

Comment: I would think the code above would almost get me there if I could find a way to tell each loop to only grab the next 1 level, which I thought $d/*/ would do, but it doesn't.

Comment: Further testing shows that the "find" commands are causing the issues as I can't stop the recursion to lower levels than the current as I don't have -maxdepth. Searches also haven't turned up an adequate workaround for this. Anyone know how to mimic -maxdepth in find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also a recursive one (I couldn't resist, sorry) ;-)

```
#!/bin/bash

#preset variables, exec redirects everything to outputfile
ROOT="/data"
LABEL="foldername.txt"
MAXDEPTH=5
DEPTH=0
HTTP="http://www.somewhere.com"
exec > "$ROOT/Menu-test.html"

#functions for indentation, definition and printing tags
LI="<LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN>"
ULecho() { Dent ; echo "<UL class='navlist$DEPTH'>"                    ;}
LIecho() { echo -n "$LI<A href='$HTTP${1/$ROOT/}/'>$( cat $LABEL)</A>" ;}
Indent() { for (( i=1 ; i < DEPTH ; ++i )); do Dent; Dent; done ; Dent ;}
Dent()   { echo -n "    "                                              ;}
LIstrt() { Indent; LIecho "$( pwd )" ; echo "</LI>"                    ;}
ULstrt() { Indent; LIecho "$( pwd )" ; echo; Indent; ULecho            ;}
TAGend() { Indent ; Dent ; echo "</UL>"; Indent; echo "</LI>"          ;}
DEPchk() { [ "$DEPTH" -gt "0" ] && ${1} ;}

:> $ROOT/$LABEL

Dive()
{
    local DPATH="$1"


    if [ "$( echo */$LABEL )" = "*/$LABEL" ] || [ $DEPTH -gt $MAXDEPTH ]
    then
        DEPchk LIstrt
    else
        DEPchk ULstrt
        for DPATH in */$LABEL
        do
            cd ${DPATH%/*}
              (( ++DEPTH ))
            Dive "$DPATH"
              (( --DEPTH ))
            cd ..
        done
        DEPchk TAGend
    fi
}

cd $ROOT
Dive "$ROOT"
echo "</UL>"
```

UPDATE:
I tried to add some of the extra's you also  mentioned but I think I do not have a detailed vision of it. Maybe because my knowledge of HTML is almost non-existent. So you really have to spell it out for me ;-)

Comment: OMG Thom, I can't thank you enough, this is brilliant and so little code, the same thing took about 40 lines of Javascript code. It's almost there then. The <UL> builds perfect. A couple of things. I have updated my question with an example using your fantastic function. As you will note, the first line of the output shouldn't be there. The 'navlist1' bit is static and not part of the directory structure, and is added separately as a variable, I should have mentioned that. So the very first line of the output should be navlist1. Therefore the navlist1 at line 9 should not be there at all..

Comment: cool :-)  , so if I understand correctly you want the lines `**<LI><SPAN class=plus><P>+</P></SPAN><A href=''>**` ,  `<UL class=navlist1>**` and the last `**</LI>**` dropped ? If you confirm this I will get to it straight away ;-)

Comment: Hi yes, that's right. The start of the menu <UL> navlist1 is hard coded at it remains static and everthing else is from the folder tree, so the first line of folder stuff should just start with <LI>. I hope that makes sense. Thanks so much.

Comment: I think this update would be an approximation of what you had in mind

Comment: Thanks Thom, this is absolutely brilliant and has also taught me so much about BASH, I can't begin to thank you enough. The HTML part of it is perfect, a couple of small tweaks was all that was needed. The only thing I need to do now is figure out how to add a different URL to the first level of folders, as those links will point to landing pages whereas everything below that will point to index pages in a different location. Will have a stab at putting a conditional around the $DEPTH variable. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Thom, all done, got exactly what I needed and have sorted out the variable URL's. I can't thank you enough for your assistance, you've taught me so much in a short space.

Comment: That is good news :-) Thank you for your kind words. I am glad I could help. It was a fun project. You're welcome any time.

Answer (score 1):

Iterative instead of recursive, which was actually not planned as such but it seemed to be an interesting way to do it.
It looks a bit messy, sorry for that.
b.t.w. I couldn't resist to do also a recursive one which looks much cleaner
(and less code; see my other answer.)

```
#!/bin/bash

#preset variables, exec redirects everything to outputfile
ROOT="/data"
exec > "$ROOT/Menu-test.html"
MAXLEVEL="*/* */*/* */*/*/* */*/*/*/*"
LABEL="foldername.txt"
NAVLIST=1
LEVEL=2
LAST=1

#functions for indentation, definition and printing tags
LI="<LI><SPAN class=plus><P>-</P></SPAN><A class=''>"
Indent() { for (( i=1 ; i < LAST ; ++i )); do echo -n "        " ; done ;}
BUecho() { Indent ; echo "<UL class=navlist""$LEVEL"">"                 ;}
EUecho() { Indent ; echo "</UL>"                                        ;}
BLecho() { Indent ; echo -n "    " ; echo "$LI""$DIRNAME""</A>"         ;}
ELecho() { Indent ; echo -n "    " ; echo "</LI>"                       ;}

# Create first level items - these are static
cat<<EOH
<UL class=navlist1>
    <LI><SPAN class=plus><p>-</p></SPAN><A class=''>Level 1 products</A>
EOH

#go to root of tree, scan tree, drop folders without label,drop labels,sort
#and start reading the result line by line .... 
cd "$ROOT" ; for SCANDIRS in $MAXLEVEL; do echo "$SCANDIRS"; done |\
grep "$LABEL" |sed "s/$LABEL/\//g" |sort |\
while [ "$LAST" -gt "0" ]
do
    #read directory entry, count slashes as depth indicator, read label
    if read LINE
    then
        LEVEL=$( tr -dc '/' <<<"$LINE" | wc -m )
        read DIRNAME < "$LINE/$LABEL"
    else
        LINE="" ; LEVEL=0
    fi

    #code logic, assembling tags
    if    [ "$LEVEL" -gt "$LAST" ];   then (( ++LAST )); BUecho; BLecho
    elif  [ "$LEVEL" -eq "$LAST" ];   then  ELecho; BLecho
    else
        while [ "$LEVEL" -lt "$LAST" ]; do  ELecho; EUecho; (( --LAST ));
        done; [ "$LAST"  -gt "0"     ] && { ELecho; BLecho;}
    fi
done
```

Comment: thanks Thom, I like what you are doing here. The function though is starting from the directory in which the script is being run, how can I direct it to the variable $ROOT, in which I have set the starting directory? I realise that var name might be a bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks Thom, we are on the right track. Your function is correctly scanning the folders/files, however it is still not maintaining the heirarchy. I added a sample output to my question to show what the output should look like.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks for the output example. Now I see what you want to archieve. I did it just the other way around. I have to rework it a bit. Please have some patience this will take some time.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I will keep having a go with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

## **I use this script for generating an html directory:**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# find ./ | grep -i "\.*$" >files
find ./ | sed -E -e 's/([^ ]+[ ]+){8}//' | grep -i "\.*$">files
listing="files"

out=""

html="index.html"
out="basename $out.html"
html="index.html"
cmd() {

  echo '  <!DOCTYPE html>'
  echo '<html>'
  echo '<head>'

  echo '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">'

  echo '  <meta name="Author" content="Bryan Guner">'
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/prism.css">'
  echo ' <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">'
  echo ' <script async defer src="./assets/prism.js"></script>'

  echo "  <title> directory </title>"

  echo ""
  echo '<style>'


echo '    a {'
echo '      color: black;'
echo '    }'
echo ''
echo '    li {'
echo '      border: 1px solid black !important;'
echo '      font-size: 20px;'
echo '      letter-spacing: 0px;'
echo '      font-weight: 700;'
echo '      line-height: 16px;'
echo '      text-decoration: none !important;'
echo '      text-transform: uppercase;'
echo '      background: #194ccdaf !important;'
echo '      color: black !important;'
echo '      border: none;'
echo '      cursor: pointer;'
echo '      justify-content: center;'
echo '      padding: 30px 60px;'
echo '      height: 48px;'
echo '      text-align: center;'
echo '      white-space: normal;'
echo '      border-radius: 10px;'
echo '      min-width: 45em;'
echo '      padding: 1.2em 1em 0;'
echo '      box-shadow: 0 0 5px;'
echo '      margin: 1em;'
echo '      display: grid;'
echo '      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;'
echo '      -moz-border-radius: 10px;'
echo '      -ms-border-radius: 10px;'
echo '      -o-border-radius: 10px;'
echo '    }'
echo '  </style>'
  echo '</head>'

  echo '<body>'

  echo ""

  # continue with the HTML stuff

  echo ""

  echo ""

  echo "<ul>"

  awk '{print "<li><a href=\""$1"\">",$1,"&nbsp;</a></li>"}' $listing

  # awk '{print "<li>"};

  #     {print " <a href=\""$1"\">",$1,"</a></li>&nbsp;"}' \ $listing

  echo ""

  echo "</ul>"

  echo "</body>"

  echo "</html>"

}

cmd $listing --sort=extension >>$html
```

#### you can then use the following to remove links to files of an undesired extension type:

```sh
sudo sed -i '/\.git/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/node_modules/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/right\.html/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/sol\~/d' ./right.html
sudo sed -i '/\.json/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.gif/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.png/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.css/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.js/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.php/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.md/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.svg/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.jpeg/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.jpg/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.scss/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/scss/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.txt/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.ttf/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.pdf/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.mp4/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.pug/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.DS_store/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.DS_Store/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.sql/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.py/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.xlsx/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.JPG/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.TTF/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.ttf/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.eot/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.ttc/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.PNG/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.java/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.png/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.jpeg/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.gif/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.go/d' ./index.html
sudo sed -i '/\.vue/d' ./index.html
```

##### the result is a directory page like so:

## [website](https://inspiring-jennings-d14689.netlify.app/)