# shell script to create a static HTML directory listing

Tags: bash, shell

So I'm creating a GitHub Pages site to list all of the Gifs in my [jglovier/gifs](https://github.com/jglovier/gifs) repo. GH Pages runs only static HTML/CSS/JS or Jekyll, so I cannot use an apache directory listing or any other server generated variant.

So what I'd like to do is run a script on the command line and have it browse the root for directories, list all the files inside (which only go one level deep), and output that to an html `ul > li > a` structure, or something similar to this:

```
root/
|
├── accidents/
|   ├── accident2.gif
|   ├── accident3.gif
|   └── accident4.gif
├── bears/
|   ├── bears1.gif
|   ├── bears2.gif
|   └── bears3.gif
└── cats/
    ├── cat1.gif
    ├── cat2.gif
    └── cat3.gif
```

I'd like the href values to be site-root relative paths (i.e. `href="/cats/cat`.gif`), and I need it to output into`_includes/site-index.html`, which will get pulled into a Jekyll layout file that wraps around my`index.md`file and generates`index.html` on build.

I [found this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275254/bash-script-to-create-a-html-nav-menu) which is very similar, and tried to implement it's answer for my purposes, but alas I'm too much of a shell n00b to accomplish it on my own.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT=/tmp/test
HTTP="/"
OUTPUT="_includes/site-index.html" 

i=0
echo "<UL>" > $OUTPUT
for filepath in `find "$ROOT" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d| sort`; do
  path=`basename "$filepath"`
  echo "  <LI>$path</LI>" >> $OUTPUT
  echo "  <UL>" >> $OUTPUT
  for i in `find "$filepath" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f| sort`; do
    file=`basename "$i"`
    echo "    <LI><a href=\"/$path/$file\">$file</a></LI>" >> $OUTPUT
  done
  echo "  </UL>" >> $OUTPUT
done
echo "</UL>" >> $OUTPUT
```

My /tmp/test

```
/tmp/test
├── accidents
│   ├── accident2.gif
│   ├── accident3.gif
│   └── accident4.gif
├── bears
│   ├── bears1.gif
│   ├── bears2.gif
│   ├── bears3.gif
│   └── bears4.gif
└── cats
    ├── cats1.gif
    └── cats2.gif
```

The resulting output

```
<UL>
  <LI>accidents</LI>
  <UL>
    <LI><a href="/accidents/accident2.gif">accident2.gif</a></LI>
    <LI><a href="/accidents/accident3.gif">accident3.gif</a></LI>
    <LI><a href="/accidents/accident4.gif">accident4.gif</a></LI>
  </UL>
  <LI>bears</LI>
  <UL>
    <LI><a href="/bears/bears1.gif">bears1.gif</a></LI>
    <LI><a href="/bears/bears2.gif">bears2.gif</a></LI>
    <LI><a href="/bears/bears3.gif">bears3.gif</a></LI>
    <LI><a href="/bears/bears4.gif">bears4.gif</a></LI>
  </UL>
  <LI>cats</LI>
  <UL>
    <LI><a href="/cats/cats1.gif">cats1.gif</a></LI>
    <LI><a href="/cats/cats2.gif">cats2.gif</a></LI>
  </UL>
</UL>
```

You could expand the UL with href too, but I wasn't sure if that's what you wanted.

```
echo "  <UL><a href=\"/$path\">$path</a>" >> $OUTPUT
```

You would have to run this in the parent folder of _includes

Comment: Wouldn't you still require the <li> tag outside each folder's <ul>?

Comment: Just fixed the script.

Comment: Why did you use upperCase of tags ? btw script is cool.. thanks

Comment: @MaherAbuthraa Maybe I thought readability was better this way, no idea. It's been three years :)

Comment: how do i run this in a windows environment? does it need a certain file extension?

Comment: @mic-anglo It's a bash script so you need a bash shell. If you need to run this on Windows you need something like "Windows Subsystem for Linux"

Answer (score 6):

`tree -H . -o _includes/site-index.html` should do everything you asked for.

There are some more options you might consider, like `-T title`. Refer to the *XML/JSON/HTML OPTIONS* section in the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/tree.1.html#:%7E:text=to%20a%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pipe.-,xml%2Fjson%2Fhtml%20options,--X%20%20%20%20%20Turn%20on).

Answer (score 3):

I know it said to use a shell script, but why not use Jekyll to do it. Github pages automatically builds the jekyll site on every commit, so you can set it up and forget about it.

#### Basic example

```
---
---

<head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Index of /</h1>
  <ul>
    {% for url in site.static_files %}
    <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl | escape }}{{ url.path | escape }}">{{ url.path | escape }}</a> </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</body>
```

#### Directory tree

```
---
---
<h1>Index of ./</h1>
<ul></ul>

<style>body{background:#303030;margin:0;font-family:Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;overflow:hidden;display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100%;width:100%}*{color:#fff;text-decoration:none}h1{background:#ff1959;font-size:1.3125rem;font-weight:500;line-height:64px;padding:0 20px;box-shadow:0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);margin:0}h1+ul{height:100%;padding:20px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden}.folder>a:nth-child(1){height:15px;display:inline-block}.folder>a:nth-child(1):hover{text-decoration:underline;text-decoration-color:#ff1959}.file{position:relative;height:50px}.file a{position:absolute;display:inline-block;height:calc(100% - 20px);width:100%;font-size:1rem;font-weight:400;line-height:30px;padding:0 10px;padding-top:4px;margin:10px 0;transition:background-color .5s ease;color:#ff6892}.file:hover a{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.1)}ul,ul.tree ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}li{display:block}ul ul{margin-left:10px}ul li{margin:0;padding:0 20px;color:#369;border-left:1px solid #ff1959}ul li:last-child{border-left:none}ul li:before{position:relative;height:28px;width:20px;color:#fff;border-bottom:1px solid #ff1959;content:"";display:inline-block;left:-20px}ul li:last-child:before{border-left:1px solid #ff1959}</style><script>var c=document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];function escapeHtml(e){return e.replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;").replace(/"/g,"&quot;").replace(/'/g,"&#039;")}for(var files=[{% for url in site.static_files %}'{{ url.path | replace: "'", "\'" }}',{% endfor %}],i=0;i<files.length;i++){var url=files[i].split("/").slice(1);console.group(files[i]);for(var x=0;x<url.length;x++){var file=url[x];if(file)for(var element=null,parent=null,y=0;y<x+1;y++){var el=document.querySelector("[ref="+JSON.stringify(y+"-"+url[y])+"]");if(!el){var type="folder";url[y].indexOf(".")>-1&&(type="file"),el=document.createElement("li");var a=document.createElement("a");a.innerHTML=escapeHtml(url[y]),a.href=url.slice(0,x+1).join("/"),el.appendChild(a),el.setAttribute("ref",y+"-"+url[y]),el.setAttribute("level",y),el.setAttribute("class",type),parent?parent.appendChild(el):c.appendChild(el)}parent=el}}console.groupEnd(files[i])}document.title=document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML+=" ("+files.length+" items)"</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Just add that first html fragment to `index.html` and run `jekyll build`? Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough with no empty dirs (although can get empty ones at end of script and append them simply anyway)

```
#!/bin/bash
root="root"
echo "<ul>"
for file in "$root"/*/*; do
  parentpath="${file#*/}"
  parent="${parentpath%/*}"
  filename="${file##*/}"
  if [[ -z $oldparent ]]; then
    echo "  <li> $parent </li>" && oldparent="$parent"
    echo "  <ul>"
  elif [[ $oldparent != $parent ]]; then
    echo "  </ul>"
    echo "  <li> $parent </li>" && oldparent="$parent"
    echo "  <ul>"
  fi
  echo "    <li><a href=\"$parentpath\">$filename</a></li>"
done
echo "  </ul>"
echo "</ul>"
```

e.g.

```
$ ./abovescript
<ul>
  <li> accidents </li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="accidents/accident2.gif">accident2.gif</a></li>
    <li><a href="accidents/accident3.gif">accident3.gif</a></li>
    <li><a href="accidents/accident4.gif">accident4.gif</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li> bears </li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="bears/bears1.gif">bears1.gif</a></li>
    <li><a href="bears/bears2.gif">bears2.gif</a></li>
    <li><a href="bears/bears3.gif">bears3.gif</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li> cats </li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="cats/cats1.gif">cats1.gif</a></li>
    <li><a href="cats/cats2.gif">cats2.gif</a></li>
    <li><a href="cats/cats3.gif">cats3.gif</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is `> ./abovescript`

Comment: @JitendraVyas meant `>` is end of prompt character, changed to `$` if that's more clear