# How to Publish Latest HTML Reports from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

We are running Selenium Tests on Jenkins and selenium generates multiple HTML reports for each build/tests per day and folder name

I would like to publish the latest HTML report from Jenkins and tried with `alwaysLinkToLastBuild` parameter but it did not work for me.

So my question is, how can I specify the latest HTML report into reportFiles due to ı've multiple with different names.

```
ubuntu@play-0:~/workspace/selenium_tests@2/p1/p2/reports$ tree

|-- oneapihub_extent_report_2020_06_25_093644.html
|-- oneapihub_extent_report_2020_06_24_093904.html
|-- oneapihub_extent_report_2020_06_23_094414.html
```

---

```
        post {
            always {
                //publish HTML report
                    publishHTML target: [
                    allowMissing: false,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: 'p1/p2/reports',
                    reportFiles: 'index.html',
                    reportName: 'HTML Report'
                ]                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general the plugin you are using is capable of doing so, but it can only publish one report. So you need a self generated `index.html` which just carries the links.

So you can run a small shell script which generates this for you after the tests have run.

Generate a list of entries in our index.html, e.g.:

```
<a href="oneapihub_extent_report_2020_06_25_093644.html">oneapihub_extent_report_2020_06_25_093644.html</a>
```

There are already good answers how to create a static list, e.g. [shell script to create a static HTML directory listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395159/shell-script-to-create-a-static-html-directory-listing)

Comment: Sorry but not clear for me. How should be the sh looks like ?

Comment: Added link to another SO post